# metafor package, rma.uni, mods, Model matrix contains character variables

Tags: matrix, error-handling, character, metafor

I'm trying to run a meta-regression with MD's as dependent variable. I want to add a numeric moderator (year published) to the rma.uni function. 
Formula so far:

metafor::rma.uni(yi=MCID12, sei=SE12, method="FE", data=Pain, slab=paste(Pain$Author, Pain$Year),  weighted=TRUE, subset=(Pain$outcomegruppe=="9"), mods =("Pain$Year") )

I always get the error message:

Error in metafor::rma.uni(yi = MCID12, sei = SE12, method = "FE", data = Pain,  : 
  Model matrix contains character variables.

My "Year" veriable is definetly numeric. As soon as I don't use the "mods" argument, everything works normal.
Could anyone help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put `Year` in quotes. Also, you don't need the `Pain$` parts and `weighted=TRUE` is the default. This should do it:

```
metafor::rma.uni(yi=MCID12, sei=SE12, method="FE", data=Pain, slab=paste(Author, Year), 
                 subset=(outcomegruppe=="9"), mods=~Year)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! Excuse my very simple question. Now everything worked out!

Comment: @mvolz Happy to help. And if this answers your question, then you might want to accept the answer.